# Qt Designer: Changing the base class of a window

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I already created a second window for my application in the Qt Designer.
I read that a QMainWindow would be the wrong class for the second window (which basically should only be some kind of dialog), so I would like to change the base class.

**My Question(s) are:**

1. Is there a way to change the base class without creating a new window and copying my code into the new files?
2. Can somebody please explain when to use QMainWindow, QDialog and QWidget? I did not found good explanations for the differences between these three base classes in Qt.

Comment: This related question helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533329/what-is-the-use-of-morph-into-in-qt

Answer (score 10):

1. To change the base class you could only change the `: public QMainWindow` to `: public QWidget` (or vice-versa) in the header-file and of course also the *.cpp.
2. Basically all three are QWidgets, each with special functionality or for specific purposes. As far as I know the QMainWindow has toolbars, menubars and docks, a QDialog will always be shown as a seperate window (e.g. blocking, non-blocking, etc.) and the QWidget itself is the base-class. I.e. QPushButton, QCombobox are derived from QWidget too. In my opinion it would be better to use only one QMainWindow since it should be a central point of interaction/navigation for the user

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that also the UI-file has to be changed, i.e. by using a text-editor, change the line (4th row I think)

```
<widget class="QMainWindow" name="YourClassName">
```

to

```
<widget class="QWidget" name"YourClassName">
```

and remove all QMainWindows related parts (menubar, toolbar, ...), and the enclosing  tag for the central widget.

Thanks to alexisdm for the tip.

Comment: Changing only the base class isn't enough: the ui file was created for a `QMainWindow` (the widget at the top of the tree in the designer), so the generated `setupUi` function still expects a pointer to a `QMainWindow`.

Comment: Tell me if Im wrong but, the UI file is autogenerated based on the .h of the class, so by changing the base-class also the .ui- AND the ui_-file is updated.

Comment: No, the ui_xxx.h file is generated only based on the .ui file. And the designer doesn't allow changing the base class of the top widget once it has been chosen, from that point the only way would be, within the designer, to copy/paste all the widgets to another ui form which would have a `QWidget` as its root and to reapply a new layout to that root (as the root layout doesn't seem to be copied with the rest). It is also possible to manually edit the .ui xml file, by removing all the `QMainWindow` related parts (menubar, toolbar, ...), and the enclosing `<widget>` tag for the central widget.

Comment: Thx @alexisdm, hope you dont mind that I added your points to my answer

Comment: I don't know why it was voted down, the answer is correct. As Robert says: change .ui in text editor, regenerate generated files, and change the base class in the code. I did it many times. It just works. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can take @Robert 's approach, but the easiest way is to create a new form class in Qt Designer, and then in Qt Designer copy the contents of your original widget and paste them into the new one.

See [also](https://forum.qt.io/topic/20723/how-to-change-my-gui-base-class-qwidget-qmainwindow/14).

Answer (score 0):

I created a new Designer Form class, once as a QMainWindow and once as a QDialog, and compared them in Git to see the differences.

Just follow the patch file, and replace the lines as needed:

```
diff --git a/mydialog.cpp b/mydialog.cpp
index e4f30f2..ccf8831 100644
--- a/mydialog.cpp
+++ b/mydialog.cpp
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 #include "ui_mydialog.h"

 MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent) :
-    QMainWindow(parent),
+    QDialog(parent),
     ui(new Ui::MyDialog)
 {
     ui->setupUi(this);
diff --git a/mydialog.h b/mydialog.h
index 8d12675..3a16393 100644
--- a/mydialog.h
+++ b/mydialog.h
@@ -1,13 +1,13 @@
 #ifndef MYDIALOG_H
 #define MYDIALOG_H

-#include <QMainWindow>
+#include <QDialog>

 namespace Ui {
 class MyDialog;
 }

-class MyDialog : public QMainWindow
+class MyDialog : public QDialog
 {
     Q_OBJECT

diff --git a/mydialog.ui b/mydialog.ui
index 6e95365..8d09b98 100644
--- a/mydialog.ui
+++ b/mydialog.ui
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
  <comment/>
  <exportmacro/>
  <class>MyDialog</class>
- <widget name="MyDialog" class="QMainWindow">
+ <widget name="MyDialog" class="QDialog">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
@@ -15,9 +15,6 @@
   <property name="windowTitle">
    <string>MainWindow</string>
   </property>
-  <widget name="menubar" class="QMenuBar"/>
-  <widget name="centralwidget" class="QWidget"/>
-  <widget name="statusbar" class="QStatusBar"/>
  </widget>
  <pixmapfunction/>
  <connections/>
```